# Script for muxing audio and video files with same name using FFmpeg

Tags: bash, shell, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a folder that contains audio and video files named like file001.wav and file001.mp4 and i want them to be muxed automatically. I've [found a script for windows](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/356314-How-to-batch-convert-multiplex-any-files-with-ffmpeg), but do not know how to alter it for OS X/Linux. Could someone help?
Here's the windows script:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.wav" -i "%%~na.mp4" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: ignore the script for a second ... do you have this working for a single call to ffmpeg ?   also your wording says mp4 yet your code shows avi ... which are you working on ? please update accordingly

Comment: I corrected the above code: I am using mp4- and wav-files. I got a single call working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should do the job:

```
for f in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "${f%.*}.wav" -i "${f%.*}.avi" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "newfiles/${f%.*}.avi"; done
```

Comment: when adding a "; done" to the line and writing "${f%.*}-neu.avi" instead of "new\${f%.*}.avi" it works … somehow the path isn't recognized.

Comment: Thanks. I miss the "; done" for the do loop. For the output part, it should be a slash instead of back slash. Of course you need to create the folder "newfiles" first.